# Microsoft Excel: Calculate hourly rate based on session rate and length

Tags: excel

I am using Microsoft Excel 2013 to do some calculations related to personal training and am a little stuck.

I would like to calculate the hourly rate based on a particular session rate and session length?

The variables are basically:

- session rate (eg say $40 in cell B6) - this is currently formatted
  via Format Cells > Category > Currency with 2 decimal figures
- session length (eg say 30 minutes in cell B9) - this is currently formatted via Format Cells > Category > Custom as h:mm

Manually I know how to work out the hourly rate above based on 30 minute sessions - I just times the session rate by 2. But it gets quite hard to do it manually for say a 40 or 50 minute session.

What formula could I use in Excel to work out the hourly rate?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Times are stored as fractions of a day so you have to multiply by 24 to get them into hours. So the answer should be

```
=B6/(B9*24)
```

but it will probably try to format this as a time and you will need to change the formatting of the result to either general or currency to make it display the right answer.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you Tom. That formula works brilliantly. I used currency formatting for the hourly rate cell. Cheers mate